# How can i resolve "throw new Error('Cannot parse privateKey: ' + privKeyInfo.message);" in Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh, cypress, ssh2

**When i run my tests, i get this error in my windows test client**

CypressError: cy.exec('npm run -s command') failed because the command exited with a non-zero code.

Pass {failOnNonZeroExit: false} to ignore exit code failures.

Information about the failure:
Code: 1

Stderr:
C:\Users\Administrator.jenkins\workspace\cypress-execution\node_modules\ssh2\lib\client.js:146
throw new Error('Cannot parse privateKey: ' + privKeyInfo.message);

Comment: `ssh-exec` hasn't been updated in about 4 years and thus its dependency semver ranges are no longer pulling in newer versions of dependency libraries (especially `ssh2`) that contain important fixes and new features. If I had to guess the reason for the error: it's because the ssh key is in the "new" OpenSSH key file format, which the much older versions of `ssh2` (actually `ssh2-streams`) do not support.

Comment: @mscdex Thanks for your input. Do you find any workaround to get it working? Where i am facing this issue is in a VM (in all three my VMs) but at the same time it is working in my laptop which is also windows.

Comment: I resolved this issue. it is strange. I created a new user and executed same script with ssh-exec and it started working. earlier i was trying with Administrator account and looks like it is blocking something from execution. Issue is resolved by creating a new user account. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

wrap your code with `try... catch` block

```
try {
   throw 'myException'; // your code goes here
}
catch (e) {
   console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: I get this error when i used ssh-exec@2.0.0 package to run my ssh cli commands. Not an issue with code. the error is thrown by ssh package

Comment: Regarding to the error message, you are missing something like private key.